# React Native - Sending a PDF with fetch but it is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, pdf

Hey guys I have a question regarding the fetch function from JavaScript and the Package Nodemailer.

**NOTE: I am using Expo.**

I have a PDF created on my Emulator which looks good (filled with data). Now I want to send this PDF to my Backend and therer I want to send the File out as a PDF and get it in my Mails.

Frontend fetch-Call for my Backend:

```
  async sendMonthReportMail(fileUri) {

    await fetch(`${connectionString}/api/mails/sendmonthreport`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        senderUser: "My Name",
        recieverMail: "myname@mymail.com",
        pathMonthLock: `${fileUri}`
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log("Success SendMailMonthLock - " + res)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log("Error SendMailMonthLock - " + err))
  }
```

I have also tried to use formData and change the Content-Type to "application/pdf" but this did not work.

Now my Backend Code looks like this:

```
  router.post("/sendmonthreport", async (req, res) => {
    const {recieverMail} = req.body;
    const {senderUser} = req.body;
    const {pathMonthLock} = req.body;

    let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "mailserver",
      port: xx,
      secure: false,          
      tls: {    
        rejectUnauthorized: false     
      }
    });

    var message = {
      from: "My Sendermail <sender@mail.com>",
      to: `${recieverMail}`,
      subject: `Mail comming from - ${senderUser}`,
      text: `EmailText `,
      attachments:[{
        filename: "MyFilename.pdf",
        content: __dirname + `./${pathMonthLock}`,
      }] 
    }    

    await transport.sendMail(message)
    .catch(err => console.log("Error Mail: " + err ))

    res.send("email send")
  })
```

Now the way that I choose the file.uri is threw the DocumentPicker for Expo.

The Problem I am having now is, that the Mail gets send correctly and there is a PDF attached to it with the correct name. **However when I look at the PDF Size it is only 500Bytes and it is completly empty**. When trying to open the File that is send via Mail then it tells me that the File is corrupted or wrong format.

How can I send the actual content that is inside the PDF?

When I try to use formData:

```
  async sendMonthReportMail(file) {

    fdPost.append("file", file);
    fdPost.append("senderUser", "User Name");
    fdPost.append("recieverMail", "username@mail.com");

    console.log(fdPost);

    await fetch(`${connectionString}/api/mails/sendmonthreport`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json"
        // "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        // "Content-Type": "application/json",
        // "Content-Type" : "application/pdf"
        // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },


      body: fdPost                                

    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log("Success SendMailMonthLock - " + res)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log("Error SendMailMonthLock - " + err))
  }
```

fdPost is defined at the top of my file, console.logging it gives me a valid FormData but the request ends with a Network Error!

```
Error SendMailMonthLock - TypeError: Network request failed
```

Also my Backend does not react to that call.

I also tried to use RN Fetch Blob but it only works in React Native only Projects. I am using Expo so this is not a soultion for me!

Edit:

I tried the suggestion in the comments (using Multer):

Frontend:

```
  async sendMonthReportMail(file) {

    fdPost.append("file", file);
    fdPost.append("senderUser", "name");
    fdPost.append("recieverMail", "mail@mail.com");


    await fetch(`${connectionString}/api/mails/sendmonthreportTest`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
      body: fdPost                                 

    })
    .catch(err => console.log("Error SendMailMonthLock - " + err))
  }
```

Backend:

```
router.post("/sendmonthreportTest", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {                                                                  
  console.dir(req.file + req.body); 
})
```

Still I have the same issue! It gives me TypeError: Network Error.

Also when I try to call that point with Postman I am getting:

```
POST /api/mails/sendmonthreportTest 500 6.952 ms - 1221
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

To confirm my POST Body when I console.log the fdPost before the fetch:

```
{"_parts":[["file",{"size":69496,"name":"Monatsbericht_User_Name_Dezember2022.pdf","type":"success","uri":"file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540yxxx%252Fxxx/DocumentPicker/2xx07e4-4136-4b6f-ad70-26xxac64064.pdf","mimeType":"application/pdf"}],["senderUser","User Name"],["recieverMail","user@mail.com"]]}
```

Comment: try to change the file format to formdata

Comment: @DiveDive I somewhat already tried this. Can you show me how you would do it in my case? So creating the FormData with my file and my other params in Body and correctly retrieving it in my Backend?

Comment: u need to add Content-Type: multipart/form-data; did u added it ?

Comment: As I stated before, show me how you would adjust the code. I cant JUST change the content-type to make it work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload Image on server using ReactNative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691379/how-to-upload-image-on-server-using-reactnative)

Comment: @user18309290 When I try to do it with FormData I get Network Error so no it does not work for me like that..

Comment: I think you are doing wrong on both BE and FE sides. You need to get the file as `File` object. And on the backend, you need to handle `multipart/form-data`. For handling multiparts with express there is a library named `multer`. I would suggest using it. Not sure how to get `File` object on the expo. The following link may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65542645/file-upload-from-react-native-expo-to-node-multer

Comment: @AdemÇırak I updated my Question after your suggestion.

Comment: @KJ What do you mean by that? I changed that part, cut out my name and put some "xxx" in there.

Comment: @KJ I have set up url encoding on my server in the index file like this: app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); but when I comment it out I still have the same error.

Comment: Is the PDF file too large to be sent over email?

Comment: @Hmkyriacou File is about 60Kb